# Change XAMPP root directory to current project folder?

Tags: php, xampp

Whenever I use the following PHP code:

```
header('Location:/account/login.php');
```

It goes to the `localhost/account/login.php` but I wish it would go to the something like this: `localhost/MyCurrentProject/account/login.php`
Cause when in the webserver the code works fine, since the server considers the root the folder of my website. Is there a way to make this automatic?

Answer (score -1):

I am using XAMPP on Windows, but the principle can be applied to Linux version.

XAMPP starts apache, and the folder with files to execute depends on its config. There are 2 main configs for that:

- Virtual hosts config: `<XAMPP>\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`
- Base config: `<XAMPP>\apache\conf\httpd.conf`

You can play with ServerRoot & DocumentRoot values in them.